# Android SlidingMenu errors When Referencing ABS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to use a SlidingMenu (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/) in my app. My first issue was that the project was using MATCH_PARENT, which wouldn't compile for me. The minSDK was set to 5, and the targetSDK was 17. I tried changing the min to 8, which is when MATCH_PARENT was introduced, to no luck.

After replacing all of the MATCH_PARENT's with FILL_PARENT's, which both compile to -1, the project seemed fine. I then proceeded to make it use ABS as per the developer's instructions on his github. Whenever I reference ABS though, I get many errors such as:

```
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:22: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values\abs__themes.xml:196: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values\abs__themes.xml:197: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values\abs__themes.xml:198: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dialog'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values\abs__themes.xml:222: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values\abs__themes.xml:223: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values\abs__themes.xml:224: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
[2012-12-02 13:53:39 - LibrarySlidingMenu] C:\Users\RynoJvR\Dropbox\Android\LibraryActionBarSerlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.
```

As far as I can tell, SlidingMenu is throwing the error because of some of the XML in ABS, meaning that R won't generate, and I can't use SlidingMenu.

Comment: Did you edit the SlidingActivity by extending SherlockActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the properties .
[image]

click on the most recent target platform (which also has google maps for mapActivity). In this image its 4.2 Google Apis